# Code first EF in ASP.NET core Web API single primary key

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using an external library to return data to me, the library has a lot of fields in it and goes quite deep with nested objects.

My class looks something like this;

```
public class Dto
{
    public Dto(Val val)
    {
        Val = val;
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Val Value{ get; set; }
}
```

And when trying to save the changes to EF I get the error;

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Value' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

When looking through the migrations it appears as if the Primary Key has been set on a few properties within the Value object. I've looked and looked but can't find a way to stop the migration automatically assigning primary keys. I've found stuff such as in the example above using the;

```
[Key]
```

attribute and adding bits and pieces into the OnModelCreating override but nothing has came up with a successful result.

Edit to give some more clarity instead of an example.

```
    [DbContext(typeof(SummonerDtoContext))]
    [Migration("20180314210242_Migration8")]
    partial class Migration8
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
#pragma warning disable 612, 618
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "2.0.2-rtm-10011")
                .HasAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy",     SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

            modelBuilder.Entity("LccWebAPI.Models.SummonerDto", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                    b.Property<long?>("SummonerId");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.HasIndex("SummonerId");

                    b.ToTable("Summoners");
                    });

                modelBuilder.Entity("RiotSharp.SummonerEndpoint.Summoner", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<long>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                    b.Property<long>("AccountId");

                    b.Property<long>("Level");

                    b.Property<string>("Name");

                    b.Property<int>("ProfileIconId");

                    b.Property<int>("Region");

                    b.Property<DateTime>("RevisionDate");

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Summoner");
                });

            modelBuilder.Entity("LccWebAPI.Models.SummonerDto", b =>
                {
                    b.HasOne("RiotSharp.SummonerEndpoint.Summoner", "Summoner")
                        .WithMany()
                        .HasForeignKey("SummonerId");
                });
#pragma warning restore 612, 618
        }
    }
}
```

and my actual data object I'm trying to store;

```
public class SummonerDto
    {
        public SummonerDto(Summoner summoner)
        {
            Summoner = summoner;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public Summoner Summoner { get; set; }
    }
```

and my context;

```
public class SummonerDtoContext : DbContext
{
    public SummonerDtoContext(DbContextOptions<SummonerDtoContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<SummonerDto> Summoners { get; set; }
}
```

I don't have access to modify the inside of the Summoner object itself to add annotations to ignore them as keys.

And the model structure of the Summoner object which I have no access to amend;

```
public class Summoner : SummonerBase
{
    [JsonProperty("profileIconId")]
    public int ProfileIconId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverterFromLong))]
    [JsonProperty("revisionDate")]
    public DateTime RevisionDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("summonerLevel")]
    public long Level { get; set; }
}
```

And the base;

```
public class SummonerBase
{
    public Region Region { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long AccountId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit : RESOLVED

After 3 hours of trying to figure this out I've finally managed to solve it, since I don't have access to annotate the models directly, I'd previously tried accessing the Ids through my SummonerDto model. Instead I accecssed them directly and it's worked.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<SummonerDto>()
            .HasKey(c => c.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Summoner>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Summoner>().Property(x => x.ProfileIconId).ValueGeneratedNever();
        modelBuilder.Entity<SummonerBase>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: is the `Val` table even represented in the database?  Showing us a `Dto` doesn't nothing for us.  Attempting to place the `[key]` attribute in a DTO won't do what you are expecting.  I am assuming this `Val` table if it does exist doesn't rely sql server to generate the `key` for that table.

Comment: @mvermef I've followed simple EF Code first tutorials that I've found online. The Migration designer is showing the values in the the Val object in there. I'll update the with a bit more of a detailed explanation instead of the example.

Comment: automatic key generation is a primary function and by convention of EF and EFC.  Just be sure you are using EF or EFCore?

Comment: I'm in an ASP.NET Core web project so I'll assume it's Core but not sure.